# No symbol named 'xxx' found in system symbol set

Tags: swift, ios-simulator

Edit: I've updated the title and question to be more specific.

I'm having trouble getting my app to run on 14.2, it runs without issue on 14.1.

The App loads 'successfully' but I'm left with a blank white screen (assume this is the loading screen) on both simulator and physical device. I get the following error on 14.2:

```
2020-11-17 12:38:38.090885+0000 TestApp[5191:233822] [framework] CoreUI: -[CUICatalog namedVectorGlyphWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:layoutDirection:glyphSize:glyphWeight:glyphPointSize:appearanceName:] 'triangle.fill' called with scaleFactor == 2.000000 glyphPointSize == 0.000000 at '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreGlyphs.bundle/Assets.car'
2020-11-17 12:38:38.091306+0000 TestApp[5191:233822] [SwiftUI] No symbol named 'triangle.fill' found in system symbol set
```

I'm not sure why it's stating No symbol named 'triangle.fill' as that is a valid SF Symbols icon.

Really would appreciate any guidance?

Comment: Does your device have the same software version as the sim?

Comment: I was actually running 14.1 on my physical device. having just updated it, I now have the same issue on both simulator and physical device.

Comment: It's probably just some kind of bug then. I'd just check the update info for clues.

Comment: I just tried it with 14.1 simulator and it works perfectly. Must be a bug with SF Symbols and 14.2 as you say. Not really sure what to do besides wait and see.

Comment: Can you describe how to reproduce this issue? `"triangle.fill"` works fine for everyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was actually related to using a TabView with PageTabViewStyle. iOS14.2 doesn't seem to like it, and was throwing all sorts of errors my way. I ended up changing my app layout, removing the PageTabViewStyle, and suddenly the 'No symbol named...' error disappeared.

Comment: Thanks Apple for letting us design apps using the layout elements we want.

Answer (score 9):

**Xcode 14.** I got the same issue while setting Image in **Swift UI**. I mistakenly provide the image name with systemName. I was loading image from Assets.

```
Image(systemName: "magazine-front-cover") //use only to load system image
```

Instead of this

```
Image("magazine-front-cover") //use to load Asset image
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me as well. My app runs great in "all" simulators, my physical iPhone 6s, iPhone X and iPad Air 2, but crashes only on my new bought iPad Pro 12.9" 2020 (all running iOS 14.2)
The strange thing is that the error appear when I use TabView in ContentView, directing me to a sub view, containing the "no symbol" mentioned in the error message. By skipping the TabView and access the sub view directly from ContentView, the sub view works great...
In addition to this, uploading the app from Xcode to iPad goes very slowly.
Turning off "Debug executable" for both "Run" and "Test" (Product/Scheme/Edit Scheme) will help on this process, and sometimes allows my app to run for a few seconds, before it freezes again.

Comment: My issue was actually related to using a TabView with PageTabViewStyle. iOS14.2 doesn't seem to like it, and was throwing all sorts of errors my way. I ended up changing my app layout, removing the PageTabViewStyle, and suddenly the 'No symbol named...' error disappeared. Not sure if this will help your situation.